# Not able to assign any scripts to my game object

Tags: unity, c#

I am not able to assign a particular C# script to a game object. When I try to do so, I get this error as shown below Only the script I have is different.
[image: error when trying to drag a script to a gameobject]
In brief, just like the error above I am getting it as `Can't Add Script Component 'AIWaypointNetwork' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and the class name match`

And when I try to create a script component, I get the warning `Associated Script cannot be loaded. Please fix compile errors and assign a valid script`. Here is a screenshot of the situation. [image: warning screenshot]

As far as I know, I don't see anything wrong with the script and it's pretty simple too.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AIWaypointNetwork : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> Waypoints = new List<Transform>();
}
```

The unity version that I am using right now is Version 2020.1.11f1 Personal. And I have not faced these types of errors before. Based on my search, I see that I would probably have to reimport assets over again. How do we do that in this version of unity?

Is there something else I am missing here?

Comment: Did you rename the script? The error box is calling the script NavAgentExample while your script is AIWaypointNetwork

Comment: @Zibelas As I had already said, I am getting the same error, but for the script that I have. Apologies for the miscommunication. What I meant to say was I am getting the error as `Can't Add Script Component 'AIWaypointNetwork' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and the class name match`. I have made the changes to the question to remove the misunderstanding